# How to calculate flux density in a toroidal CT that has an electrical line pass through the center?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, density, conductors

I have seen the Biot–Savart equation, but I don't know how to apply it. Does the conductor length need to be considered finite and equal to the core length, or will the calculation be for a conductor of infinite length?

Comment: What is CT?  Please don't assume we all know the acronyms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you assume infinite conductor length but this only means the vectors disappear in this special case of circular current loops (B field at the center of a loop is the same distance from all points of the loop). and a toroidal winding is simply N number of loops.

therefore you use Biot Savart law to calculate B field provided by one loop,and multiply by N number of windings to find total B field in the core  (essentially Amperes Law). of course with experience you can immediately use Amperes law in this problem by drawing a circle following the core which incidentally encloses the entire current carrying conductor.

Comment: The flux is generated by one single conductor running through the center of the toroid, so no turns on the toroid.